# Какую функцию выполняет файл __main__.py?

Tags: python, импорт

Какую функцию выполняет файл `__main__.py`?

Например файл `__init__.py` импортируется при импорте пакета.
Судя по всему файл `__main__.py`, тоже выполняет какую-то особенную функцию.

Объясните пожалуйста какую именно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Файл `__main__.py` служит точкой входа в приложение, если мы запускаем наш модуль через командную строку с флагом `-m`. Таким образом это позволяет нам использовать модуль как отдельное приложение.

```
python -m your_app
```

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал, но решил уточнить.